# Google App and Google Plus not Updating to their new logos in APP LAUCHER

Tags: android

Even after google changed their logos, my app icons of Google, Google Maps, Google Plus etc are not getting updated to their new logos (**ONLY IN THE APP LAUNCHER**). In the Apps Section under Settings however, the apps are being shown with their new logos. I have the updated versions of these apps and whenever I open them, the new version of the apps open. But the LAUNCHER ICONS remain the same. I am running Lollipop 5.0.1 on Micromax Canvas Spark Q380. Any help?

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore off topic on this site. Try asking your question on [su] or [android.se].

Comment: This belongs in [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/)